# New Swift 3 Warning Crashes App

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

when i implement either proposed fix the app crashes when run.  When i compile/run the app without the recommended fix the app runs as expected.

[image: screen shot of error is at this link]

the original method is as follows:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    //this let statement is my original line of code prior to swift 3 conversion and it worked fine
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier:"Cell")

    //i've tried using the statement below instead but still getting same error
    //let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = userSummaryArray[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row] as String
    cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name:"Helvetica Neue", size:17)

    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator

    userSummaryTable.rowHeight = 25

    return cell

}
```

after converting to swift 3 in Xcode8 i'm now getting a warning on this method that reads:

```
Instance method 'tableView(_:cellForIndexPath:)' nearly matches  optional requirement 'tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)' of protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'
```

There are two options recommended to "fix" the warning:

```
Make 'tableView(_:cellForIndexPath:)' private to silence this warning
```

OR

```
Add '@nonobjc' to silence this warning
```

Both of these "fixes" crash the app.  the original code works fine in the new swift and worked fine in the older version of swift.  what are these recommendations?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

Make that

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

instead of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
```

Xcode is trying to help you but does not recognize that

Comment: i changed to your suggestion but my app crashed when run so i've reverted back to the 'func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {' code and the app runs successfully;  but i still have no resolution to my original question....why am i getting the two warnings  related to this method?

Comment: you just need to follow autocomplete and it will work, clean project and please show your method added from autocomplete and what exactly crash error says, when there is a crash there have to be some message

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Along with Lu_s answer, make sure you add UITableViewDataSource to the class.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {   }
```